# Remove part of character string in data frame

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I'm struggling to delete the strings `"D_1__"` , `"D_2__"` , `"D_3__"` , etc. in a `data.frame` while keeping the succeeding text, i.e. input: `"D_1__succeeding text"` output: `"succeeding text"`.

I tried

```
df <- gsub("D_.__", "", df)
```

but nothing was changed

Further the columns of the imported `data.frame` are `factors` with more than one level. May this be causing the problem and how can I convert the `df`?

Thanks a lot for you help!

Comment: I don't know but this works for me : `gsub("D_.__", "", df)` returns `"succeeding text"`

Answer (score 2):

You are facing two issues: `gsub` is designed to work with character vectors, not entire data frames, and you are also dealing with factors instead of a character vector.

I'm not sure how you are importing your data, but you probably have the option to use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` to prevent the strings being read as factors in the first place, e.g. for CSV data:

```
df <- read.csv('mydata.csv', stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Alternatively, you could convert your factors to strings:

```
df$myvar <- as.character(df$myvar)
```

Once you have a character vector, you can use gsub pretty much like you had it, just specify the variable:

```
df$myvar <- gsub('D_.__', '', df$myvar)
```

Finally, if you did want to leave your variable as a factor, you could rename the levels instead:

```
levels(df$myvar) <- gsub('D_.__', '', levels(df$myvar))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
strings <- c("D_1__text1" , "D_2__text2" , "D_3__text3")
new_strings <- gsub("D_\\d__", "", strings)

> new_strings
[1] "text1" "text2" "text3"
```

If it is a problem with your specific data add a `dput(your_df)`. I think your problem was how you are trying to store your result. Something like `df$colnew <- gsub(..., df$colold)` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestions. Finally, I managed to convert my df to a character matrix by:

df <- data.frame(lapply(df, as.character), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

Then I applied:

gsub('D_.__', '', df$V1)

for each column separately. For just 15 columns this was quite feasable :-)